# How do I make a track report from my Django models in a way that the report also has its auto-incremented primary key?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have 3 models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    roll_number=models.IntegerField(primarykey=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=60)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Course(models.Model):
    roll_number=ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=CASCADE)
    course=ForeignKey(CourseChoices, on_delete=CASCADE)

class Fee(models.Model):
    roll_number=ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=CASCADE)
    amount_to_be_paid=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    discount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Final_amount_to_be_paid=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Amount_received=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Balance=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    batch=models.CharField(validators=[batch_pattern])
```

**Now, whatever data these tables hold, I want to display them together as:**

[image: Sample Track Report]

I want each and every transaction to be tracked by a separate track id. The track id should be auto-incrementing, unique key. How do I achieve this? I tried creating one more model while applying multiple inheritance on it but It clearly couldn't work. That way, the user would have to enter the data in the table created by the last model where all the fields would be available to fill but the scenario cannot allow this as each forms would be filled on separate days, not at once. So the complete information are to be entered separately, so forms are divided. But I want them together to track each transaction with a track ID. I'm a beginner and just trying stuffs here but I'm constantly failing since almost a week now.

Any suggestions, please!! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would `Fee.id` work?

Comment: BTW, depending on the database, the default automatic IDs may occasionally skip a value (when an insert fails, it may nevertheless get a number). Depending on your country, it may be illegal to skip invoice numbers. If that's your situation, you may need to handle invoice numbers manually rather than relying on the automatic ones.

Comment: @sabik, No, it's not gonna be an invoice number, just a key for the user to track the transactions.
As for your comment about the ` Fee.id ` working or not, I might have to check its behaviour first, strange it didn't occur to be at all. I'll let you know.